# Convert tilde separated string to array with PHP

Tags: php

How can i convert following string in array and what is the common name of that string pattern?

```
text^name1^Peter~text^secondname1^Wayland~text^email1^pw@Weyland-yutani.com~text^phone1^(000)000-00-00
```

Comment: first time I see something like that in my life :) where did you get that from?

Comment: parse to what? how can *common name* help you?

Comment: you can use `explode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Some applications stored values in database in that format. Sorry, i updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on `~`, then, split each part on `^`:

```
<?php

$data = 'text^name1^Peter~text^secondname1^Wayland~text^email1^pw@Weyland-yutani.com~text^phone1^(000)000-00-00';

$result = [];
foreach (explode('~', $data) as $keyvalue) {
    list($type, $key, $value) = explode('^', $keyvalue);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [name1] => Peter
    [secondname1] => Wayland
    [email1] => pw@Weyland-yutani.com
    [phone1] => (000)000-00-00
)
```

Note that this does not handle any other record type than "text", and I don't know what happens when a value contains a `^` or a `~`.